# series battery connection with different voltages

Tags: battery-charging

I am trying to make 9.6 V out of 8 AAA rechargeable 1.2 V batteries. My answer is to make a series connection.

I have two 3 battery holders and one 2 battery holder for my 8 batteries. Now can I connect those three battery holders to make 9.6 V. I know that I need batteries of the same type and voltage and capacity, but technically all these batteries are the same. Will it work?

Comment: yes. Why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

From the title it seems you're concerned that the two three-cell packs will total 3.6 V each and the one two-cell pack will put out 2.4 V.  Connecting eight 1.2 V cells in series will give you 9.6 V.  It makes no difference that they are in different packs.  Think of the internal connections in the holders, and the wires between the holders, all being zero ohms.  The physical grouping of the cells makes no difference to the total voltage.

Comment: I like your nickname. It's very unix-y.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should work just fine! Though, with those pack connectors the resistance is often higher than you might like, so depending on the load you are supplying with the batteries you might see the voltage drop a bit below your expected 9.6V from the voltage drop across all the connection wiring.

Is there a specific concern you have as to why it might not work that we can address?